# a Sum that no longer evaluates

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, summation, backslide

**Backslide introduced in 7.0, fixed after 11.0, in or before 12.3.**

---

At http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2000/Sep/msg00318.html and http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1999/Jul/msg00375.html we see an apparently successful evaluation of the expression

```
Sum[Sin[(n + 1)*Pi] - Sin[n*Pi], {n, 1, Infinity}] + Sin[Pi]
```

Mma 11 (Win 10) does not successfully evaluate this expression.  One supposes that this is a change in some default (`Method`?).  Can evaluation still be forced somehow?

I am already aware that `Limit` accepts domain restriction assumption. My question is about `Sum`.

Comment: Seems to be a quite old [backslide](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backslide), which is introduced in or before v8.0.4. (I don't have an older version installed…)

Comment: This backslide is introduced in _v7_:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsCat.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuOR0.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's code now works in V12 & V13 (tested in 13.0.1):

```
Sum[Sin[(n + 1)*Pi] - Sin[n*Pi], {n, 1, Infinity}] + Sin[Pi]
(*  0 *)
```

Comment: You might want to add that it also works in `V12`

Comment: @kcr Thanks, I did not know that. (Got a new computer and don't have V12 anymore.)

Comment: yeah, I know how it is. for me it's the other way around. I am trying to leave my old laptop with `V12` for my new macbook with `V13` but I have so many stuff going on, that I end up using the old one....(sighs) :-)

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
Sum[Sin[(n + 1)*Pi] - Sin[n*Pi] && n \[Element] Integers, {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

> 0

It appears that one has to specify explicitly the domain of the index of summation.

Comment: Odd.  Is that restriction not implicit in the iterator?  Any idea why the original expression no longer evaluates?

Comment: Interestingly, without `n \[Element] Integers` and summing over `{n,1,Infinity,1}` also does not evaluate. Moreover, adding `GenerateConditions->True` also doesn't evaluate and doesn't return the conditions. But `Sum[Sin[(n + 1)*Pi] - Sin[n*Pi], {n, 1, z}, 
 GenerateConditions -> True]` gives `ConditionalExpression[Sin[\[Pi] (1 + z)], 
 z \[Element] Integers && z >= 1]` suggesting that MMA doesn't treat `Infinity` as an integer so it does not know how to proceed with the evaluation. Although I cannot be sure what sits behind it.

Comment: `Sin[(n + 1)*Pi] - Sin[n*Pi] && n \[Element] Integers` seems to me to be very strange syntax.  Is it meaningful to `And` a function evaluating to a real number and a boolean?  I can see that if the boolean part evaluates to true, the `And` will be eliminated.  Note sure why that helps in this case.

Comment: @mikado Actually `Simplify[Sin[(n + 1)*Pi] - Sin[n*Pi] && n \[Element] Integers]` is `-2 Sin[n \[Pi]] && n \[Element] Integers`. That is why it works.

Comment: @yarchik  With that insight, we expect to be able to `Sum[Simplify[Sin[t \[Pi]] - Sin[(t - 1) \[Pi]]], {t, 1, \[Infinity]}]`, which is in fact the case.

Comment: @Alan, strange, I get 0 for your example...., but see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give first a short answer. With only one keyword added you achieve the desired result:

```
Sum[Sin[(n + 1)*Pi] - Sin[n*Pi], {n, 1, Infinity}, Regularization] + Sin[Pi]
```

Notice also, that this procedure is well defined mathematically. Pushing the limits leads to paradoxes. Consider the following:

```
b Sum[ b^n, {n, 0,Infinity}] - (Sum[b^n, {n, 0,Infinity}] -1) // Simplify
(*0*)
```

Thus we can define $x=\sum_0^\infty b^n$ and write the above formula for, say, $b=2$:

```
b x - (x - 1) == 0 /. b -> 2
(*1 + x == 0*)
```

or $x=-1$, which is a rather strange result for the sum of all-positive elements....

Comment: What value did you use for `Regularization`?  I'm not getting an effect from any of the documented possibilities.  Your "paradox" can be more simply illustrated: `Sum[b^n, {n, 0, \[Infinity]}] /. {b -> 2}`.  This happens because Mma assumes convergence, despite the default of `VerifyConvergence` being true.  Bug?  Bad design?  Good design but requiring user care?  I'd prefer to have to specify assumptions on `b`.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that we can get the desired result by mapping `Simplify` (suggested by @Alan)

```
Sum[Sin[(n + 1)*Pi] - Sin[n*Pi], {n, 1, Infinity}]
MapAt[Simplify, %, {1}]
(* 0 *)
```